# is it possible to view a question with a browser before importing it to Moodle?

Tags: moodle, r-exams

I have created a XML file using R-exams out of just a single exercise to be imported to Moodle. I would like to view it before uploading it in the Moodle question bank. I tried to open it with Firefox and I can see some code but not the output and a message appear saying that the XML file does not seem to have a style sheet associated to it. Is there a way to find this style sheet and to see how the question comes out just using a browser like Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: `exams2html` or `exams2pdf` would be enough?

Comment: Currently, I use `exams2pdf` to have a preview, but `exams2pdf` does not always behave exactly as `exams2moodle`. So I wonder whether it is possible to use a browser or another program to open the XML file and view the output or the only way is uploading it to the Moodle question bank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To emulate how the R/exams exercises are converted to HTML by `exams2moodle()` and how Moodle displays mathematical content, it's best to use

```
exams2html(..., converter = "pandoc-mathjax")
```

In recent versions of R/exams the resulting HTML file then automatically loads the MathJax Javascript that enables correct rendering of mathematical content in all modern browsers (including Google Chrome). See also http://www.R-exams.org/tutorials/math/ for some general advice about math in HTML.

To the best of my knowledge there is no tool that would quickly display Moodle XML files in such a way that you can easily assess them.

Comment: Thank you! I have a question. I usually write      `exams2moodle(ex, n=1, dir="moodle", edir="../esercizi", converter = "pandoc-mathjax", cloze=list(cloze_mchoice_display="MULTICHOICE_V"), stitle=ex, schoice =list(eval = list(partial = TRUE, rule = "none")), name=ex)`      but if I try to replace `exams2moodle` with `exams2html` I get an error message. What would be the correct syntax for using `exams2html` instead of `exams2moodle` but with the same (or similar) options?

Comment: `exams2html()` does not provide any automatic evaluation. Hence it does not support many of the arguments from `exams2moodle()` such as `cloze`, `schoice`, and `stitle`. See `?exams2html` for more details.

Comment: Ok. I understand that `exams2html` does not provide automatic evaluation. But  the option `cloze_mchoice_display="MULTICHOICE_V` is not about the evaluation. Isn't there an equivalent for `exams2html`?

Comment: No, the "vocabulary" for that option is Moodle-specific.